# Multiple Forms in One Page (MVC3)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 3 and I'm trying to create a edit view for a User-object that has a couple of relations. I have the basic edit-view for the user, split with tabs for each relation that needs to be handled.

Tab 1 = Edit User
Tab 2 = Create new Group Access (with a listing of current group access)
and so on...

I created a ViewModel for the edit-view:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public GroupAccess GroupAccess { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GroupAccess> GroupAccessList { get; set; }
}
```

The edit-view:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.UserViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="span9">
        <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">User Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Group Access</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                    @{ Html.RenderPartial("User/_CreateEditUser", Model.User); }
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                    @{ Html.RenderPartial("User/_CreateGroupAccess", Model.GroupAccess); }
                    @{ Html.RenderPartial("User/_ViewGroupAccessByUser", Model.GroupAccessList); }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_SidebarPartial"); }

</div>
```

Each of the partialviews are strongly-typed against their respective object...

The partialviews posts to the same controller, UserController, to separate actions. Everything works fine when saving "correct" data but when some kind server-side error occurs I need to return to the edit-view somehow. If I receive a server-side error in the "CreateGroupAccess" action in the UserController...how do I get back to the edit-view with the UserId-parameter that is required?

I'm stuck and I'm guessing that I'm going in the wrong direction with the current solution.

Does anybody got any idea on how to best solve this scenario?

Comment: In this case you need to use ajax. Or post to server full information that is needed to reconstruct whole model.

Comment: Use RedirectToAction, and pass the userId in the RouteValueDictionary

Comment: I would suggest doing client side validation so that the user can see problems as soon as they occur, and before they leave the tab they're on.  Then you won't have the problem of a "hidden error" on some other tab.  (that is the problem, right?)  Still do the server side checks as you are, just in case, but the vast majority of your users will not get over on your client side checks.

Comment: Yeah, but I still want to know how one should handle this...In my scenario I have client-side validation that just validates so that the 2 dropdownlists aren't empty...the server-side validation makes sure that the specific accesstype to this specific group for this user already isn't in place...If that validation fails...how do I return to previous view? If I do RedirectToAction(), then I'll lose all the validation messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make yourself an BaseController:

***BaseController***

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
   protected const String ModelStateTempData = "ModelStateTempData";
   protected Boolean PreserveModelState { get; set; }

   protected override RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        if(PreserveModelState)
          TempData[ModelStateTempData] = ModelState;

        return base.RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      if (TempData[ModelStateTempData] != null && !ModelState.Equals(TempData[ModelStateTempData]))
            ModelState.Merge((ModelStateDictionary)TempData[ModelStateTempData]);

      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

***SomeOtherController***

```
public class SomeController : BaseController {
  public ActionResult SomeAction(FormCollection collection) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
      //Do something
      return SomeThingValidHappened();
    }

    //Not Valid
    PreserveModelState = true;
    return RedirectToAction("myAction");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't receive any messages when trying out the BaseController example.